# How to set focus on TextBox (previously the focus was on this TextBox) on KeyPress event of DataGridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, textbox

This is my code:

```
private void gv_old_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == 27)
    {
        gv_old.Visible = false;
        // And want focus on that TextBox
    }
}
```

What I want is to focus on the previous TextBox when the focus was on the  DataGridView.

Comment: To get attention, you should add more (applicable) tags!

Answer (score 1):

Let just say you have a textbox below :

```
TextBox textbox1;
```

You can set focus on the textbox like this,

```
textbox1.focus();
```

Comment: please be more specific.

Comment: add id to your textbox and use that id on setting focus, replace `textbox_id` with the id of your textbox

Comment: this is for winforms don't have any option to set id to textbox

Comment: this is the simply way but i don't know  which textbox the user is using that's the problem.the only known thing is "previously the focus was on that textbox".

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
yourTextBox.Focus();
```

Comment: i don't know the textbox because user can select any textbox